# Is there a way I can return terms by name using a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, terms

I want to create a shortcode to return a string of values, which are the term names. So I can use it to pass data inside a plugin. Anyone cracked this one before?

```
/**
 * Custom shortcode to get terms for the Formidable plugin
 */

function ALC_post_terms_by_id( $term, $atts ) {
    global $post;

    $alc_Terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $term, 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0' );

    $term_array = array();
    foreach ($alc_Terms as $alc_Term) {
        $term_array[] = $alc_Term->name;
    }

    // $atts = shortcode_atts( $term_array() ), $atts );

    return $term_array();
}
add_shortcode( 'term_by_id', 'ALC_post_terms_by_id' );
```

---

**New attempt**

This is the shortcode I use:

```
[get_terms_by_taxonomy taxonomy="bouwjaar"]
```

This is the new function after suggestion in the comment by *TheDeadMedic*

```
/**
 * Custom shortcode to get terms for the Formidable plugin
 */

function ALC_post_terms_by_taxonomy( $atts ) {

    // return $atts['taxonomy'];

    $taxonomyTerms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $atts['taxonomy'], 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0' );

    $term_array = array();
    foreach ($taxonomyTerms as $taxonomyTerm) {
        $term_array[] = $taxonomyTerm->name;
    }

    return $term_array; // returns "Array"

    // return implode( ', ', $term_array );
    // implode returns "nothing"
}
add_shortcode('get_terms_by_taxonomy', 'ALC_post_terms_by_taxonomy');
```

Comment: Have you tried `return implode( ', ', $term_array );` instead?

Comment: hm almost there. Tried what you suggested, but the implode returns nothing after I pass the array trough it. I'll re-edit te code above.

Comment: Found it. Your solution did work, I forgot to add the `global $post` inside the function:). Thanks for the help! Should I add the full function for future reference?

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution to get post terms by taxonomy by shortcode:

```
/**
 * Custom shortcode to get terms
 */

function ALC_post_terms_by_taxonomy( $atts ) {

    global $post;

    $taxonomyTerms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $atts['taxonomy'], 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0' );

    $term_array = array();
    foreach ($taxonomyTerms as $taxonomyTerm) {
        $term_array[] = $taxonomyTerm->name;
    }

    return implode( ', ', $term_array );
}
add_shortcode('get_terms_by_taxonomy', 'ALC_post_terms_by_taxonomy');
```

And you can use it by this shortcode:

```
[get_terms_by_taxonomy taxonomy="taxonomyname"]
```

Comment: This shortcode will get the terms in use, that is, on the very post, if you want to get terms from taxonomies in general should use get_terms https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/